# Постоянно увеличивать значения массива на 12

Tags: javascript, html

Есть массив чисел `let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]`
При клике на кнопку должны получить массив длиной 12 с числами [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
И так до бесконечности - при следующем клике - [25,26 ... 36]
Не знаю как заставить числа в массиве увеличиваться после второго клика

Comment: [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function increaseItemsByTwelve(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    arr[i] += 12;
}

let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
increaseItemsByTwelve(a);
console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
increaseItemsByTwelve(a);
console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
increaseItemsByTwelve(a);
console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
```

Comment: то что нужно! спасибо

Comment: @Volodymyr298 Пожалуйста. "Галочка" - слева.